# Framework7 onPageInit behaviour Inline Pages vs Ajax Pages

Tags: html-framework-7

When using Inline Pages, the onPageInit runs only once on first load of the inline page, then the onPageReinit is triggered every time the page is revisited.

When using Ajax Page, the onPageInit is triggered every time the page is revisited.

Is this the behaviour by design?

If so, is there an event that is only triggered once on the first visit to the page?